# Webpack build error: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '*.js -> '*.webpack.js']

Tags: webpack

A little bit of context for this one, I have this following folder structure. My program in particular is `issuetrax` (for reference to the image)

[current folder structure for error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLZA0.png)

I keep getting the following error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '*.js -> '*.webpack.js']
```

I've also deleted `node_modules`, `yarn.lock` (it's a new module so no worries there) and `esm`.

What's causing it to snag?

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that if there is only ONE folder under lib (that being `issuetrax` in my case), it'll just assume that folder is the root and ignore the rest of the structure. This causes Webpack to misplace files and then hence our problem.

To fix this, add this property to to your `"compilerOptions"` in `module.tsconfig.json`:

```
"rootDir": "./<name-of-root-folder>"
```

In my case, my root folder was named `lib` but you can name yours accordingly.

You can also add more folders/files to your root directory and that fixes the problem as well. Either way, Potato Tomato.